# Making a lexical analyzer WITHOUT manually walking / checking

Tags: python, parsing, compiler-construction, lexer

I'm making my own programming language and I'm on the lexer right now. My current approach is to manually walk through the code and check for valid keywords, then append a `Token` object to a `tokens` array. But it leaves me with a massive if/else statement that's not only ugly but slow too. I'm struggling to find any resources about this online, and I'm trying to find out if there's a better way to do this - Some regex pattern or something?

Here's the code

```
class Token:
  def __init__(self, type, value):
    self.type = type
    self.value = value

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Token({self.type}, {self.value})'

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()


def lex(code):
  tokens = []

  for index in range(len(code)):
    pass # This is where the if/else statement goes

  return tokens
```

I don't want to use lex or anything. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using a parser generator.  For Python, https://wiki.python.org/moin/LanguageParsing seems to have plenty of options.

Comment: Also, having file-position metadata in your *Token* type can help you later craft good error messages.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'm trying to make it from scratch

Comment: Ok.  So a personal goal of yours for this project is to learn about writing lexers and/or parsers?

Comment: Lexers are simpler, but note that _for parsers_ hand-rolling one is almost categorically a Very Bad Idea. This is an area where there's solid CS theory -- dating back to the mid-1900s -- that immensely improves implementation quality; hand-built parsers are often inconsistent and buggy. Get a good textbook -- the Dragon Book ([Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)) is classic -- if you're serious about learning the topic; folks trying to play it by ear result in abominations like csh.

Comment: The Dragon Book was great back in the 1990s.  There've been plenty of better books written since.  For example, it says nothing about how to write incremental compilers that work well with modern IDEs.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Yeah, this is just a personal project. I'm trying to learn more about compilers/interpreters.

Comment: As others have noted don't reinvent the wheel. As I note to beginners, your fingers should not be on the keyboard until you understand the problem and algorithms needed and are merely entering code to automate the process. If you have not done some of the key parts with pencil and paper then you are not programming but hacking in the bad sense of the word.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hm. I (and many people who are substantially more experienced than I) disagree with this. Yes, for quick DLSs parser generators are great tools. But for proper programming languages a hand-written parser has many advantages.

Comment: @BrandonDev The *Dragon Book* is indeed a classic but it is seriously dated, and heavy on theory. I recommend [*Crafting Interpreters*](https://craftinginterpreters.com/) by Bob Nystrom instead. It is free to read online, easy to follow, and 100% practical. Here's the the code I wrote when following along the first part of the book (which implements a full programming language): https://github.com/klmr/pylox

Comment: Since the OP notes `I'm making my own programming language` and there are some book recommendations. One of the most important and first items on the list for designing the grammar is to know if the grammar is [ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar), while that may be a problem for many it is not a death sentence but someone new to creating grammars is a very hard lesson to learn the hard way, it might take them many months to years before they realize it is the fatal flaw in their language. cont.

Comment: If a recommended book does not address ambiguity head on showing examples, possible work arounds or how to deal with it, then I would not use the book as a primary reference. :-). I program in [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog) parsing with [DCGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) and [open list](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/difference-list/959) so ambiguity is something I am quite familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Parser generators can help you get started quickly by helping you define syntax trees and giving you a declarative syntax to describe the lexing & parsing steps.

> that's not only ugly but slow too

This seems odd to me.  Hand-rolled lexers usually are pretty performant.  As long as your syntax doesn't require too much [lookahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Lookahead) or back-tracking.

Parser generators typically work based on automata; they build state tables so most of the work is just a loop that at each steps looks up into those tables.

One trick that high-performance, hand-rolled lexers often do is to have a lookup-table that classifies each ASCII character.  So the lexing loop looks like

```
while position < limit:
  code_point = read_codepoint(position)
  if code_point <= MAX_ASCII:
    # switch on CLASSIFICATION[code_point]
  else:
    # Do something else probably identifier related
```

where `CLASSIFICATION` stores info that lets you recognize that quote characters inevitably lead to parsing as a quoted string or character literal and space characters can be skipped over and 0-9 inevitably lead to parsing a numeric token.

> Some regex pattern or something?

This can work if your lexical grammar is [regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar).

That probably isn't true if your syntax requires nesting tokens.

For example, JS has non-regularity because template strings can embed expressions:

```
`string stuff ${ expressionStuff } more string stuff`
```

so a JS lexer needs to keep state so it knows when a `}` transitions back into a string state or not.

Comment: I'll have to look into lookup tables, because that's probably what I'm looking for. I'll also check if mine would work with regex, but with what you said, it probably won't. Thanks for the help, hopefully it'll solve my problem

Comment: Re the JS example: alternatively, it's not the *lexer's* job to parse a template string.

Comment: The original question doesn't suggest nested tokens, so there's no reason (so far) to think that regex wouldn't work.

Comment: “Hand-rolled lexers usually are pretty performant.” — Yeah but this is *Python* we’re talking about. Having a loop over the input with a huge `if`/`match` statement is orders of magnitude slower than in statically typed, compiled language.

Comment: @MichaelDyck So would regex work for a normal programming language syntax? I was thinking about it and I was wondering how it would tokenize strings correctly (Like knowing that in `print("hello")` hello is a string)

Comment: @MichalDyck, if it's not the Lexer's job when do you find quoted token boundaries?  Something needs to recognize that there is no comment start when the template string contains slash star.  You can use a scannerless parser, but that just means you're roling the Lexer's job into the parser.

Comment: @BrandonDev, yes.  Regular expressions will work if your lexical grammar is regular.  That's not true for a surprising number of widely used PLs, but if you're designing the language, then you can take that as a goal.

Comment: @MichaelDyck you are correct that the original question didn't suggest a non-regular lexical grammar.  I was trying to help the OP in case they had plans in that direction.